# Android Studio app using Django back-end login authentication?

Tags: android, django, cookies

I've recently been working on an Android app using Android Studio which is using a Django backend. The web application is already in place I just want to make the app in Android for it.

The problem I am running in to, which is mostly because I'm new to app development, is the login authentication. I've researched on this topic here and I understand theoretically how I should go about doing this, but I have not been successful in logging in from my app.

The problem I have is this:

1. I get a csrf token authentication failure. It states that the cookie is not set. I understand that a post request will return this.
2. I am always getting a success transition in my doPost method.

I currently am lost in how to check if I have actually logged in or not. And the only solution I thought of for the cookie not being set is to do a Get request, parse the cookie as a string and pass that in to the post request. But I'm not sold on it being the best strategy. The bigger problem is not being able to tell if I have actually logged in or not. How can I check that? I have read posts on kind of explaining how to do this but as a beginner it is hard to translate that to code. How do I check if the user was actually authenticated? Any and all help is appreciated.

```
 public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;


    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", mEmail));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));
        String response = null;
        String get_response = null;
        try
        {

            response =  SimpleHttpClient.executeHttpPost(localLoginUrl, postParameters);
            Log.d("Login Activity","Post Response is: " + response);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Login Activity","Error is: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


   public static String executeHttpPost(String url,
                                     ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Django view:

```
def login_view(request):  # Login page view
    form = login_form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = login_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():  # check if form is valid
            user = authenticate(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password'])  # authenthicate the username and password

            login(request, user)  # login the user

            # Once logged in redirect to home page            
            response = HttpResponseRedirect("/"+some_user_url+"/home")
            print "USER KEY IS: %s" % some_user_key
            response.set_cookie('some_user_key', value=some_user_value, max_age=some_max_age, secure=SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE, httponly=False)
            return response
    else:
        form = login_form()  # Display empty form

    return render(request, "login.html", {  # loads the template and sends values for the template tags
        'form': form,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the questions was asked quite a long time ago but, since there's no answer, and I'm working quite intensively with Django recently, I thought to share my very basic knowledge, hoping it will be of help for others.

The way you are dealing with the CSRF token is the correct one: first you perform a get of the login page which will give you the CSRF token in the cookie. You store the cookie and the CSRF token and you embed them in the following POST request, together with authentication data. If you get a 200 OK from the server it already means you correctly used the CSRF token, and this is an awesome start :)

In order to troubleshoot whether the user has actually logged in or not, that is whether it's credentials were accepted, you can print out the payload of the HTTP response you obtained from the server.

I use a function which prints me the response of the server in case I get an error code greater than 400. The code is the following:

```
public static boolean printHTTPErrorMsg(HttpURLConnection c) {

    boolean error = false;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        builder.append(c.getResponseCode());

        builder.append("\n");
        builder.append(c.getResponseMessage());
        System.out.println("RESPONSE CODE FROM SERVER");
        System.out.println(builder);
        InputStream _is;
        if(c.getResponseCode()>=400){
            error = true;
            _is = c.getErrorStream();
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(_is));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return error;
}
```

You need to tweak it because when you get a 200 OK from the server, there's no ErrorStream but simply an InputStream. So if you change your if condition to =200 and replace the getErrorStream() with getInputStream() you'll see in the log what is actually the content of the response of the server. Typically, if the login failed, the response will contain most likely the HTML code of the login page with the error message saying you provided wrong credentials.

Hope this helps